# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Literature's [first moderator election](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Rand al'Thor] [image: Tsundoku]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4729808539877376/0).

Answer (score 6):

### Thank you ...

- to those who voted, no matter who for (I'm flattered and humbled to have been so far ahead in round 1);
- to heather and Skooba for running and making it a good contest;
- to Tsundoku for running and for everything you've done already making you such a strong candidate;
- to Gallifreyan for carrying the Literature mod duties alone for so long.

Looking forward to working with Tsundoku and Gallifreyan! I've always loved this site, and I'm honoured to be elected as a moderator here. To all: let me know if I mess anything up :-)

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations! Both you are very deserving and I am glad to be part of a site that will have you added to moderation team. It was an honor to compete against you both!

Since you are both moderators on other sites already I have no doubt you will fill the roles perfectly.

Comment: Thank you! Hope you'll continue to stick around and be an active voter ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I sure will. Maybe I can some more review in now too!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to both the new moderators! Both of you will be exemplary at your job :)

Comment: Thank you! You said "*I would certainly start coming by more if I became a mod*", but I hope to continue seeing you around anyway :-)