# Timeline of Literature moderators

Tags: support, moderators

Inspired by [Timeline of Parenting moderators](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1251), this post is intended to record the history of Literature SE diamond moderator teams over time. To make it an actual "question":

Who has moderated Literature Stack Exchange? What have been the moderator teams over the years since 2017?

Comment: The [election page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election) can help provide a visual guide of when elections happened and the results. However, as detailed in your answer it does not cover the pro-tem appointments nor the resignations/account deletions (although that can be worked out if an election winner no longer has a diamond next to their name).

Answer (score 5):

Two clarifying notes:

1. Some people changed their usernames between becoming mods and stepping down. I've decided to use only the *most recent* username on their account in such cases, in order to minimise confusion. You will see other names being used in older meta posts, though.
2. Some former mods have entirely deleted their accounts. For the avoidance of doubt, "Aza" was user80 and "Hamlet" was user111. I hope they won't mind me referring to them by their usernames rather than account numbers.

---

**22 Feb 2017**: [Mithical, Aza, and Hamlet appointed as moderators](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/521/1). (There were no elections for pro-tem mods in 2017; these people were selected by Community Managers, but there was an [informal nomination thread](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/351/17) starting on **30 Jan 2017** in which these three were, at the time of choosing, the highest voted nominees.)

- *Mod team: Mithical, Aza, Hamlet.*

**24 Oct 2017**: Hamlet resigns as moderator. ([First public mention on 26 Oct](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40779982#40779982), but it happened quietly on 24 Oct.)

- *Mod team: Mithical, Aza*.

**2 Jul 2018**: [Gallifreyan appointed as moderator](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/521/4). (Again, at this time there were no elections for pro-tem mods.)

- *Mod team: Mithical, Aza, Gallifreyan*.

**26 Sep 2019**: [Aza resigns as moderator](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/17).

- *Mod team: Mithical, Gallifreyan*.

**17 Oct 2019**: [Mithical resigns as moderator](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1200/17).

- *Mod "team": Gallifreyan*.

**28 Apr 2020**: [Rand al'Thor and Tsundoku elected as moderators](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1259/17). (This was the first moderator election held on Literature, with the [nomination process starting](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination) on **13 Apr 2020**; it was a pro-tem election, meaning that all mods would need to re-run at site graduation in order to keep their diamonds.)

- *Mod team: Gallifreyan, Rand al'Thor, Tsundoku*.

**27 Jul 2021**: [Mithical re-appointed as moderator](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1594/17). (As a moderator who stepped down in good standing, they were able to reclaim their diamond without need for any election process.)

- *Mod team: Mithical, Gallifreyan, Rand al'Thor, Tsundoku*.

**24 Feb 2022**: [Gallifreyan resigns as moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60511045#60511045).

- *Mod team: Mithical, Rand al'Thor, Tsundoku*.

**12 Apr 2023**: [Mithical and Rand al'Thor re-elected and Matt Thrower elected as moderators, Tsundoku elected not to run for re-election](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1769/17). (This was the first *full* moderator election held after Literature's graduation, with the [nomination process starting](https://literature.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=nomination) on **28 Mar 2023**; existing mods who didn't run [or, hypothetically, who ran and lost] would lose their diamonds.)

- *Mod team: Mithical, Rand al'Thor, Matt Thrower*.